# "Enforce Unique values" will it works when the list get larger?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, enforce-uniquevalue

I have an Asset list, and I want to enforce unique values on the built-in Title field at the list level, but I have a question if this enforcement has any limitation when the list gets larger? or it is supposed to work all the way?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: It should work without any issue, every asset in list should have unique Title.